# C# SerialPort. Do I still need to add \\.\ to the port name (above 9)?

Tags: c#, serial-port

I do not have any device to test it (which will come up as a COM port having the number 10+). Do I still need to add`\\.\` or was it sorted out in NET6?

Comment: Maybe you could try this tool to have a port number above 9. http://www.advancedvirtualcomport.com/advancedvirtualcomport-help/index.htm  . I have a dotnet core 3.1 console  and  doesn't use prefixes

Comment: You should be able to change the COM port number to any number manually by Device Manager. If a COM port exists, why not change it and check it?

Answer (score 0):

Testes and it does not require `"\\.\"` in front of the port name